# Changing Navigation Bar Background Colour?

Tags: html, css, navigation, hyperlink

I am currently trying to design a navigation bar for one of my websites. This navigation bar will be across the top of the webpage.

The problem is that I can get the items to change colour when I hover over them, but cannot get the items to stay in the hover state once the page is active. So for example, if I wanted to go "Home", I would hover over the "Home" item in the navigation bar, and it would turn gray, when I click on it to go back to "index.php" the "Home" in the navigation bar would stay gray. (With the background of the navigation bar being black).

I have formatted a table with a single row, and a few pieces of data, which will serve as links. This is what the HTML code kind of looks like:

```
<div id="header_banner">
<table id="header_banner_table">
    <tr id="header_banner_row">
        <td id="header_banner_a"><a class ="link1" href="">Item 1</a></td>
        <td id="header_banner_b"><a class ="link1" href="">Item 2</a></td>
        <td id="header_banner_c"><a class ="link1" href="">Item 3</a></td>
        <td id="header_banner_d"><a class ="link1" href="">Item 4</a></td>
        <td id="header_banner_e"><a class ="link1" href="">Item 5</a></td>
        <td id="header_banner_f"><a class ="link1" href="">Item 6</a></td>
        <td id="header_banner_g"><a class ="link1" href="">Item 7</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is some of the CSS:

```
#header_banner {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 71px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header_banner_table {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}

.link1 {
position: relative;
display: block;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 23px;
padding-bottom: 23px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}

.link1:hover{
position: relative;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
padding-top: 23px;
padding-bottom: 23px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
background-color: gray;
}
```

So currently the background of the navigation bar is black, and when you hover over something, it turns gray. I would like it to stay gray when that page is active.

Any solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
:focus
```

or

```
:active
```

But I think it needs to be clicked on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the active state only applies when the button is being clicked, and not after. So if you hold the click down on the button, then it will activate.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with jQuery? If I'm thinking the same thing as you are you should be able to do it with jQuery.

```
var path = window.location.pathname;

$('#header_banner_row a').each(function(){
    if( $(this).attr('href') === path ){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

So basically, `var path` is whatever is after .com in the navigation bar in your browser. And if that path is the same as one of the `a` in the header, it will get a class of active that you can style to be gray.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am unfortunately not familiar with jQuery. I am not exactly sure what you mean, or how to implement it. Could you please show me?

Comment: Include `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the head of your site, and after jQuery has been included you can include a `script.js` that will hold the code above. Just make sure you have `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ // your code here });`. If the script isn't wrapped in a ready function things will go wrong. Also, it's best-practice to include custom scripts before the closing body tag.

Comment: Thanks again. I made up another solution, which I am finding is helping me in loads of other cases as well. I am using PHP to conditionally apply CSS Stylesheets. I'm not sure whether this is an acceptable method of doing it, but it works.